# ActionSheetの選択肢の内の一つからAlertへ遷移することはできますか？

Tags: swift

いつもお世話になっております。
今回の質問は、

・UIButtonからActionSheetを表示
・ActionSheetの選択肢の内の一つを選択
・Alertを表示
・画面遷移

という展開が可能か？ということです。

ネット上にある情報では、
UIButton　→　ActionSheet
UIButton　→　Alert
というサンプルコードは見つかるんですが、今回の質問のような複雑なものが見つかりません。

是非、ご教授下さい。

Comment: ActionSheetのUIAlertActionの中でAlertを表示する関数を呼び、その中のUIAlertActionの中でperformSegueWithIdentifierを呼んで画面遷移する、という感じになると思います。まずはそれだけのプログラムを作ってみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
最初のActionSheetのUIAlertActionの中に下記、
addTarget(self, action: "showAlert:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
を入れようと思ったのですが、addTarget(　の前に通常はUIButtonの名前を入れるようですが、
今回は、アラート内のためボタンの名前がありません。
そこが知りたいのです。
お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addTargetはUIButtonでイベントが発生した時に実行するインスタンスとメソッドを登録する為のもので、ActionSheetのAlertActionの中で実行しても、そこでaddTargetしたものが実行されるわけではありません。おそらく再度ボタンをタップすると、ActionSheetの表示とaddTargetしたメソッドが同時に実行されるのではないでしょうか。

以下のように記述するとご希望の動作になると思います。

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(sender: UIButton) {
    let actionController = UIAlertController(title: "sheet", message: "please select", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    actionController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "first", style: .Default, handler: { [unowned self] (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: sender.currentTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "transition", style: .Default, handler: { (transitionAction: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("transition")
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

ActionSheetのUIAlertAction内でUIButtonであるsenderを参照してタイトルを取得し、それをAlertのタイトルに設定しています。
addTargetなどの基本的な事柄をご理解されていないようなのでその点学習されると良いと思います。

Comment: アドバイス有難うございます。理屈がわかりました。今開発中のコードに組み込んだところ、Missing argument for parameter #1 in call　とエラーが立ちました。調べたところ、引数を指定しないでfunc showAlertを呼び出したようです（私のコードではshowAlertという名前にしてあります）。しかし、この場合の引数が何なのか？わからない上に、どう引数を指定するのか？がわかりません。そこで再び質問ですが、今回教えていただいたActionSheet→Alertの流れは、一つのfuncの中に入っていないとダメですか？現在私は、別々のfuncにしていて、ActionSheetに設定していある条件を満たした時、Alertに飛ぶようにしております。重ねてご教授お願いします。

Comment: ActionSheet→Alertの流れはalertControllerの作成以下のコードをshowAlertメソッドに記述する事で分ける事が可能です。エラーが発生するshowAlertの記述とその呼び出し部分のコードを質問に追記していただければ、問題点を指摘しやすいです。

Comment: 有難うございます。引数を適当に入力したらできました。有難うございました。